# Android Running Timer

Tags: android

I am calculating creating apps for Online Shopping in which i am having a Deals Start Date and End Date..

From this two date i want to calculate the time remaining for the Deal to end in Seconds basis.. I calculated remaining days,seconds,hours,minutes..

I want to display the Remaining time in Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds format...

Although i move to next activity this time should runs in background in which the second must updated every seconds..

If i move this activity again i want to display the Updated Remaining time...

Also in my UI the Remaining time must get reduced second by second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building a service I would create a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Handler.html) that updates your Userinterface.
You can now call [sendEmptyMessageDelayed](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessageDelayed%28int,%20long%29) with a delay of 1000ms. In the [handleMessage](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Handler.html#handleMessage%28android.os.Message%29) method you can update your UI and call sendEmptyMessageDelayed again.

Don't count on Android to call you exactly in time. recalculate the remaining time every now and then instead of just decreasing it by one.

If the activity is in the background you shouldn't update the UI because the activity is paused. Just disable the whole updating process in the [onPause](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method and reenable it in your [onResume](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method. If you method is destroyed from the system while it was in the background your onCreate method will be called again and you have to recalculate the actual remaining time.

Make sure you understand the [ActivityLifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) Process before implementing this changes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a Service and an Activity with the Service performing the timing operation and the Activity presenting the time information.